# Java Vs Scripting for HDFS map/reduce

Tags: hadoop, scripting

I am a DB person, so java is new to me. Looking for scripting language for working with HDFS, may be Python I am looking for. But I see in one of the previous question, you mentioned that "Heart Beat" between Name and Data node will not happen if we use scripting language. Why, I could not understand? As we are writing our application logic to process data in the scripts or java code, and how it matter for the "Heart Beat"?

Any idea, on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is good choice for hadoop if you know already how to code with it. I've used php and perl with success. This part of Hadoop framework is called [Streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html).

For "Heart Beat" I believe you are thinking of Counters. They are user defined "variables" that can only be incremented. Hadoop will terminate task attempt if no counters are incremented for 10 minutes. However you shouldn't worry about this as there are system counters that are automatically incremented for you. If you do have a job that takes very long, you can still use counters with Python (Hadoop Streaming) by sending something like this to standard error output:

```
reporter:counter:MyGroup,MyCounter,1
```

For more info on counters with Hadoop Streaming see [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html#How+do+I+update+counters+in+streaming+applications%3F)